# How would I get this Route to post to my database successfully? Getting error 500

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have my api.php setup so it goes:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CalendarController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post("/home",[CalendarController::class, 'add']);
Route::post('/event/create', [CalendarController::class, 'add']);
```

I then have it set up so in my home.blade.php it fetches the api/event/create endpoint and attempts to post to it:

```
            const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token][content]").content;
            console.log(csrfToken);
            fetch('/api/event/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
                },
                body: encodeFormData(eventData)
              })
```

Issue is that when the code is run, it outputs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhAR6.jpg
Are there any errors within my code? I am able to log the csrfToken successfully though, but am not sure if it passes on to the server correctly. Thanks all for any help.

Output in laravel.log:

> [2022-03-01 17:04:14] local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::show does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\Http\Request::show does not exist. at C:\xampp\htdocs\Room Booking System VUE\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php:113)

The CalendarController in my case has a setup of this, where I'm not sure if it is working with 'Request' properly:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Booking;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $events = array();
        $bookings = Booking::all();
        foreach($bookings as $booking) {
            $events[] = [
                'title' => $booking->title,
                'resourceId' =>$booking->resourceId,
                'start' => $booking->start_date,
                'end' => $booking->end_date,
            ];
        }
        return view('home', ['events' => $events]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops! Should've included that as well, i've edited my post now thanks.

Comment: So yeah, using `Request::class` instead of the Controller is your issue here. See the answer below and adjust as required 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Path\To\EventController;

Route::post('/event/create', [EventController::class, 'store']);
```

You should put EventController::class (or whatever your controller class) and second array element should be your method inside this controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Booking;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $events = array();
        $bookings = Booking::all();
        foreach($bookings as $booking) {
            $events[] = [
                'title' => $booking->title,
                'resourceId' =>$booking->resourceId,
                'start' => $booking->start_date,
                'end' => $booking->end_date,
            ];
        }
        return view('home', ['events' => $events]);
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request){
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add that I have my path to the controller as well, edited my post :). Could you clarify what you mean by the second array element? Thanks.

Comment: Is CalendarController has add method in it? Can you check your log again and send it to?

Comment: I believe so, here is the link to my log https://www.justbeamit.com/umu8f

Comment: You have to create a create method inside EventController.php

Comment: You should start to read Laravel documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers

Comment: I've given that page a good read-through many times over but am still struggling to understand how I can 'create the create' method. How can it help with creating an add method? Thanks for the help :)